# select2 getting value of selected option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```html
<select id="category" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="category" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
          <option value="1">ICT</option>
</select>
```

I want the above output when Adding option in my select2. I initialize my select2 like :

```js
var site_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
var URL = site_url + "Autocomplete_Control/autocomplete_category";
$('#myModal select').css('width', '100%');
$('#category').select2({
  tags: false,
  multiple: false,
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
  ajax: {
    url: URL,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: function(params) {
      var queryParameters = {
        term: params.term
      };
      return queryParameters;
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            text: item.category_name,
            id: item.sys_id
          };
        })
      };
    }
  }
});
```

I want to get the value `1` from the option when I select `ICT`.

The way I get is :

```js
$('#category').on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
  // what you would like to happen
  var category_id = $(this).select2().find(":selected").val();
  console.log(e.target)
  console.log(category_id)
  console.log($("option:selected", e.currentTarget).val())

  console.log($('#category').select2('data'));
  particular(id); //i want to send the ID for another select2
});
```

All the above returns `undefined`.

How to get the value `1`

I want to get the value of 1 because I will use it in another select2 as parameter. There I will select all particular which is having the `category_id` of `1`. Assuming that the `value=1` is the `id:sys_id` from the initialization of the select2.

Comment: You can also use `<select id="category" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="category" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
          <option value="1" selected>ICT</option>
</select>` and it will work fine in select2

Comment: I have a problem with my solution though. When I use the below solution I cant use scroll i dont understand why

Comment: An `HTML` solution is much better than a `js`,  I use  a function similar to yours for getting the text - `$(this).select2().find(":selected").text();`, about the scroll issue i don't have encountered it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#category').on("change", function(e) {
  // what you would like to happen
  var category_id = $(this).select2().find(":selected").val();
  console.log(category_id)
});
```

I used the regular `change` event and it returned the correct for `$(this).select2().find(":selected").val();`